# Misshapen Mesh FBX Export

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, export, .fbx

Here's the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k2E0v2a3YTJyuV6bu-ufYU2I-x5RcEn8/view?usp=sharing).

Steps:

1. Select everything.
2. File ‣ Import/Export ‣ FBX (.fbx)
3. Turn on Selected Objects.
4. Export FBX
5. Upload character to Mixamo.

[image]

Expected:

- Smooth surface
- Uniform color

Results:

- Areas around the mouth and neck are misshapen.
- Head is grey. Body is white.

I'm worried that this might become a larger issue when I start to rig and animate this. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on Face Orientation in the overlay dropdown and you'll see that the whole head and neck apart from the lips has the normals inverted.
[image]

In edit mode, select all and then ALT-N > Recalculate Normals.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: No problem. If it helped, please mark the answer as accepted.